# Se puede instalar python en un pendrive

Tags: python, tkinter, flask, pygame

Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de instalar python en un pendrive, mi problema es que hace un tiempo no tengo una computadora en mi casa y me gustaria usar python y algunas librerias en la computadora de mi trabajo, pero no quiero instalarlo directamente en el disco duro para que no se den cuenta, probe instalar algunos juegos viejos directamente en el pendrive y funciono pero me surgio la duda si podria hacer lo mismo con python, actualmente uso el navegador para programar algunas cosas con la plataforma de replit.com y similares, pero es muy limitado para las cosas que me gustaria hacer.
Se les ocurre alguna solucion para mi problema? muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si se puede, el programa se llama WinPython. puede leer como hacerlo. [python portable](http://blog.espol.edu.ec/ccpg1001/descargas/winpython-portable/)

Answer (score 3):

Pues suponiendo que en el trabajo tengas permiso para usar USB, y dependiendo del Sistema Operativo que use en dicho ordenador hay varias vías para conseguir lo que deseas.

*Ya han mencionado WinPython, para windows, aunque creo no se puede usar para XP o anteriores.

*Otra opción es Anaconda, tiene versión portable.

*Y otra posibilidad es un Linux en un USB preparado con "persistent storage". Ya que llevan Python por defecto. Live Ubuntu es fácil y muy cómodo para eso. Un Live Linux USB tiene como ventaja que los programas y los cambios realizados se pueden guardar en el mismo USB dentro del sistema.

Salud.